# Open pdf from c# with Process.Start: Adobe Reader closes after 3 seconds

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, pdf

Using `Process.Start("myfile.pdf")` from main thread opens Adobe Reader with the correct file, but closes it after 3 seconds.

Same with `Process.Start("myfile.txt")` keeps Notepad open. When I switch to Chrome as the default pdf-viewer, the Window is also kept open.

How do I keep the Reader alive?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "closes it" - you may mean one of two very different things. Are you literally saying that a window showing the PDF disappears? Or are you saying the the `Process` that was started exits?

Comment: The Window disappears. It seems to be a Reader problem, see my added "Chrome as default"

Answer (score 1):

The default application was not Adobe Reader as I mentioned, but Acrobat Version 7 (oldish). After installing the Reader and being forced to uninstall Acrobat (krrr, Adobe.....), things worked as expected.